# Close a Process when main application exits or crashes in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, exit

I have a Mono c# application (App1) that launches a native application (App2) using Process and Process Start Info.
Everything runs smooth but I would like to have some kind of handler, event or whatever so I can be notified that app1 has been closed so i could call App2.kill(). 
Currently when app1 is closed, app2 keeps running and that's not desirable.
I've seen that in Microsoft's .net there are Application.OnExit events available and such, but seems there's nothing like that in Mono.
Has anybody faced a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Thank you in advance,

Toni

Comment: Application.OnExit is from WPF. What kind of application is App1? i.e. GTK, Console, WinForms, etc?

Comment: It's a GTK# application. It launches 2 Webkit windows (using webkit-sharp) to show 2 web pages and then a native c++ application using Process.Start.
The webkit windows are closed when the application is closed, as they're part of the same process, but the native C++ app keeps opened as it's a different process